# Does continuity not imply existence?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading [these lecture notes](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/complex-analysis/complex_analysis.pdf) and there is a converse to the Cauchy Riemann equations and it is stated as follows:

If the partial derivatives exist and are continuous then $f$ is (complex) differentiable.

> My question is: Doesn't continuity imply "exist"? Meaning, we could
>   just say if the partial derivatives are continuous then $f$ is
>   differentiable? Or what does "exist" mean in this context? I assumed
>   it meant "is finite".

Comment: Well, perhaps a student will prove that the derivative of some function is continuous at each point of the derivative's domain, but forget to prove that the domain is all of $\Bbb C$. So they want to stress that the function has to exist everywhere.

Comment: My dog can speak. Did this statement do anything to assert the existence of this dog?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Didn't a famous mathematician once say, "Your dog can speak.  Therefore, it is."?  I would simply state ... Your dog can speak?  How many languages?

Comment: @Dr.MV: I never bought into the whole cogitus approach.

Comment: @asafkaragila He did have a useful coordinate system ... "I think."  Anyway, my attempt at humor.

Comment: @Dr.MV: Frege had some great ideas. I'm not going to take his advice about antisemitism, though.

Comment: @asafkaragila You do realize that I was just making light of things.  On a serious note, I didn't know Frege was antisemitic.

Comment: @Dr.MV: I know I know. You can look it up. He was a misogynistic antisemitic introvert.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting caught up in something that has nothing to do with math.

I would read "partial derivatives are continuous" and "partial derivatives exist and are continuous" the same exact way. The latter is just more explicit. Either way, this really is a minor thing that has little to do with math.

Comment: @GitGud No worries.

Comment: However, while it's true that it is a minor thing that he's getting caught up on, paying close attention to the details and subtle nuances of statements is very important.